# module 'e3tools.ml_bench' has no attribute 'et'

Tags: python-3.x

Hello I'm having issue with this cell, first the imports

```
{enter code here
import e3tools.eda_table as eda
import e3tools.ml_bench as mb
import e3tools.eda_display_utils as edu
import e3tools.eda_display_js_utils as edju
import e3tools.notebook_utils as nu
from importlib import reload
}
 reload(mb.et); reload(mb)
 dt_params = {'dtype':'datetime', 'format':'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'}
 et = mb.MLTable(processed, c_label='ErrorBool', dtypes= 
{"TimeInHour":dt_params})

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
```

in 
      1 import e3tools as et
----> 2 reload(mb.et); reload(mb)
      3 dt_params = {'dtype':'datetime', 'format':'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'}
      4 et = mb.MLTable(processed, c_label='ErrorBool', dtypes={"TimeInHour":dt_params})
      5 # et = mb.MLTable(csa_train, c_label='error_bin', tbl_h=csa_test,

AttributeError: module 'e3tools.ml_bench' has no attribute 'et'

any ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score -1):

the ans to the question is the version of e3tools,  was 0.0.0 should have been 0.0.5,  then all is good
regards
Jeff